# python can not import docx

Tags: python, windows-10, modulenotfounderror, mu

I will state that my goal was simply to write to a docx file for the following reasons:

1. I am building a study guide and I thought have a little automation to do so in the labeling process would be easier
2. I like to challenge myself to make my code work

I have tried:

- pip install python-docx
- pip install docx
- pip uninstall python-docx
- pip uninstall docx
- pip3 install python-docx
- pip3 install docx

Though I am still getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` error message, could anyone think of what to try next?

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "c:\users\xxx\onedrive\desktop\my programs\having fun.py", line 2, in 
> import docx
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'

Comment: What version of python are you running?  According to what I read python-docx is dependent on Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, or 3.4.

Comment: I am running 3.9, I will see if I can get it to work with one of the ones listed, but I am not sure if I actually addressed the real issue I am having, I am trying to write to a .docx file, now I can get it to open in google docs, but it will not open in word. Is there something I am missing / do I really need to import docx?